# How does the ruby vulnerability affect me?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

Visiting this site: http://ruby-doc.org/

I get this message:

> There were 3 Ruby vulnerability reports in the last 14 days. 2 high, 1 medium. Most recent: CVE-2013-4562. See details.

I only installed ruby for fun and to play with it. Does this vulnerability affect me? I'm really afraid what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CVE-2013-4562](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-4562) is a CSRF vulnerability in the "omniauth-facebook". Since whatever app you're developing is only available on your local machine, there's no way for an attacker to exploit this.

[CVE-2013-5671](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-5671) is a vulnerability in the image processing library which allows attackers to execute malicious code as the user Ruby runs as with a specially crafted image file. As always, your app is only available on the local machine and the only way to exploit this is to convince you (the user) to download that image and pass it through this library.

[CVE-2014-0130](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0130) is a vulnerability that allows an attacker to read any file from the filesystem using a specially crafted request, assuming that the user Ruby runs as has the permissions to read this file. This is probably the scariest one of all three, but as always since your app is only available from your machine and isn't open to the internet, you are safe.

You are safe as long as your app isn't open to the entire internet (your router/firewall takes care of that).